# VMWare Player in Ubuntu 17.10 does not start

Tags: vmware-player

I successfully installed VMWare Player in Ubuntu 17.10. After that VMWare Player is not starting after clicking on the icon. Are there any more steps after running the .bundle? Please hep.

Comment: You might ask beware as it is 3rd party closed source app. https://communities.vmware.com/thread/574379

Comment: Run it from the terminal 'vmplayer'. Then you will see what it is complaining about.